# Mysql RELEASE_LOCK is not releasing lock

Tags: java, mysql, spring

In my java application, multiple threads are running concurrently to acquire different named locks using mysql GET_LOCK. Some times intermittently even though when one thread is releasing the lock using RELEAS_LOCK its not getting released(result of RELEASE_LOCK execution is returned as 0)

Can anyone help me to understand why this happens?

Comment: Can you help us with some code to analyze the problem ?

Comment: Please refer to this and reformat your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Try to provide examples and explain your progress as well as your progress when trying to solve this problem yourself. for example: I have tried to rebuild the project and this and this happened.